# How to output a string in lisp without quotes and without returning anything?

Tags: string, return, output, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to lisp programming and i was wondering how do you output strings without quotes and without returning an object (that includes not returning a `nil`) like most languages?

```
std::cout<<"Hello world\n";
```

I know the `format t` function does that but it still returns `nil` isn't there a way to output without nil and quotes? Is it possible?

Can someone point me to Lisp tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/user/CBaggers/videos) or [this](http://www.shedai.net/ai/tutorial.html#Printing) but with more detailed documentation and explanations?

Comment: FORMAT does not output NIL additionally. If you have a question, please show code, an example and the actual description of the desired behavior and a description of the error. Don't forget the code...

Comment: Well I want to print only and nothing but Hello world!without quotes and without nil
If I type (format t "Hello world")-this will output Hello world with nil
but if I do (format nil "Hello world")-it will output "Hello world"

I'm asking if there's a way to output only Hello world?

Comment: What's wrong with FORMAT? You need to show what you are doing. We can't guess your  code.

Comment: FORMAT NIL does output nothing. It returns a string.

Comment: but with quotes

Comment: I think you were talking about output, not about returned values?

Comment: In c++ we output like std::cout<<"Hello world\n";

and we get Hello world and nothing else

I'm asking if it's possible to achieve the same thing?if yes how?

Comment: Show us an example interaction.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cJ5uLS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The REPL prints the value of each expression it executes**

If you use the READ EVAL **PRINT** LOOP, the REPL will print the result. That's why it is called Read Eval Print Loop.

But output functions themselves will not print their result.

```
CL-USER 1 > (format t "hello")
hello      ; <- printed by FORMAT
NIL        ; <- printed by the REPL

CL-USER 2 > (format t "world")
world      ; <- printed by FORMAT
NIL        ; <- printed by the REPL
```

Now combine the above:

```
CL-USER 3 > (defun foo ()
              (format t "hello")
              (format t "world"))
FOO

CL-USER 4 > (foo)
helloworld     ; <- printed by two FORMAT statements
               ;    as you can see the FORMAT statement did not print a value
NIL            ; <- the return value of (foo) printed by the REPL
```

If you return no value, the REPL will print no value.

```
CL-USER 5 > (defun foo ()
              (format t "hello")
              (format t "world")
              (values))
FOO

CL-USER 6 > (foo)
helloworld   ; <- printed by two FORMAT statements
             ; <- no return value -> nothing printed by the REPL
```

**You can execute Lisp code without a REPL**

If you use Lisp without a REPL, no values are printed anyway:

```
$ sbcl --noinform --eval '(format t "hello world~%")' --eval '(quit)'
hello world
$
```

Alternatively you can have Lisp execute a Lisp file:

```
$ cat foo.lisp
(format t "helloworld~%")
$ sbcl --script foo.lisp
helloworld
$
```

The actual command lines are implementation specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This is the first time I encounter REPL.And you did answer my question(which I am grateful) can you point me to some detailed documentation please for REPL and for everything if not can you recommend books?
Thank you!

Comment: @jakHunter: free beginner books: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/  and  http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

Comment: As another option one can make an executable: `sbcl --no-userinit --load foo.lisp --eval "(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die \"a.out\" :toplevel 'foo :executable t)"`